# Searching to two words using boolean operator

Tags: search, boolean

I would like to make search based on boolean operator. for example Cat AND Dog. I have a text file with lots of word under certain url address. so when I enter cat OR dog in command line. it should return url addesses of where one of the word is found or both in case of AND. I use java and netbean program

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex search. This can be done very easily in python. Search for url address in text file,  which consist word dog and cat.

```
regex Ex:  r'Cat'|'Dog'
```

Comment: I have a text file that looks like text below and I want to search for words and display url of that word using boolean IT AND på                    *PAGE:http://www.it-c.dk/Internet
Aktuelt
på
IT
højskolen
*PAGE:http://www.it-c.dk/Internet/jobs
Stillinger
på
IT
højskolen